# Is there a way to find the cause of unexpected power offs by inspecting logfiles?

Tags: logs, system-failure

My openSUSE 15.2 notebook has experienced three unexpected shutdowns in the last four weeks. By unexpected shutdown I mean that the system simply turns off without my intention, as if it had suddenly lost power. In each of these cases, the battery had at least 70% of its capacity or (as today) the notebook was connected to the docking station. (This system is less than 6 months old.)

At the time when these poweroffs happened, the system wasn't running any heavy tasks, the RAM (32 GB) wasn't nearly full, and the applications that were running were typically Firefox (with at most a few dozen tabs), Skype, a programming editor (typically Geany; last time also jEdit), Dolphin (under KDE) and (last time, but not today) LibreOffice and Terminator. I often have VeraCrypt running, but it was not running when today's power off happened. In other words, I can't explain the power off based on the applications that were running.

Today, I have looked at logfiles in `var/log` (those that had changed today), e.g. `lastlog`, `wtmp`, `snapper.log`, `warn` and `messages`, and I also looked at a dump of `sudo journalctl --since today > /home/.../journalctldump`, but I am not sure what to look for.

In `var/log/warn` I found lines such as the following from around the time of the poweroff:

```
2020-11-24T13:21:50.752712+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [    4.379766] nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
2020-11-24T13:21:50.752850+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   37.414546] printk: systemd: 20 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
2020-11-24T13:21:50.752866+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   37.732271] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for AC is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
2020-11-24T13:21:50.752880+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   38.143654] tuxedo_keyboard: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
2020-11-24T13:21:50.752915+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   38.224654] iwlwifi 0000:40:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
2020-11-24T13:21:50.752916+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   38.224783] iwlwifi 0000:40:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
2020-11-24T13:21:50.752917+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   38.224816] iwlwifi 0000:40:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
2020-11-24T13:21:50.752918+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   38.224829] iwlwifi 0000:40:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
2020-11-24T13:21:50.752949+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   38.723137] thermal thermal_zone2: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
2020-11-24T13:21:50.752705+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [    4.339343] Disabling IRQ #31
2020-11-24T13:21:50.753541+01:00 tuxedo smartd[1862]: Device: /dev/nvme0, number of Error Log entries increased from 194 to 195
2020-11-24T13:21:50.840587+01:00 tuxedo systemd-udevd[1348]: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl restore 0' failed with exit code 99.
2020-11-24T13:21:51.089561+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   39.186997] uvcvideo 1-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
2020-11-24T13:21:51.089573+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   39.186999] uvcvideo 1-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
2020-11-24T13:21:51.089574+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   39.187000] uvcvideo 1-7:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
2020-11-24T13:21:51.156094+01:00 tuxedo colord[2446]: CdMain: failed to search machine directories: Error opening directory '/var/lib/colord/icc': Permission denied
2020-11-24T13:21:51.158112+01:00 tuxedo colord[2446]: failed to get session [pid 1870]: No data available
2020-11-24T13:21:51.176194+01:00 tuxedo colord[2446]: message repeated 3 times: [ failed to get session [pid 1870]: No data available]
2020-11-24T13:21:51.185861+01:00 tuxedo systemd[1]: cups-browsed.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2020-11-24T13:21:51.600090+01:00 tuxedo postfix/postmap[2986]: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: localhost
2020-11-24T13:21:51.632302+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   39.729450] usb 4-1.1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=767), cval->res is probably wrong.
2020-11-24T13:21:51.632314+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   39.729454] usb 4-1.1: [4] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 2, val = -4592/7680/16
2020-11-24T13:21:51.632315+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   39.729989] usb 4-1.1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=672), cval->res is probably wrong.
2020-11-24T13:21:51.632316+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   39.729991] usb 4-1.1: [7] FU [USB Audio Playback Volume] ch = 6, val = -10752/0/16
2020-11-24T13:21:51.666542+01:00 tuxedo systemd-udevd[1318]: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
2020-11-24T13:21:51.752292+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   39.849288] iwlwifi 0000:40:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
2020-11-24T13:21:51.756296+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   39.853105] iwlwifi 0000:40:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
2020-11-24T13:21:51.888748+01:00 tuxedo systemd[1]: Failed to start VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
2020-11-24T13:21:51.888900+01:00 tuxedo systemd[1]: Dependency failed for VirtualBox Linux autostart module.
2020-11-24T13:21:51.889265+01:00 tuxedo systemd[1]: vboxdrv.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2020-11-24T13:21:51.932314+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   40.027760] iwlwifi 0000:40:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
2020-11-24T13:21:51.936306+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   40.031315] iwlwifi 0000:40:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
2020-11-24T13:21:52.604697+01:00 tuxedo postfix/postmap[3647]: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: localhost
2020-11-24T13:21:53.508321+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   41.604269] evdi: [I] Initialising logging on level 5
2020-11-24T13:21:53.615216+01:00 tuxedo postfix/postmap[3847]: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: localhost
2020-11-24T13:21:54.624623+01:00 tuxedo postfix/postmap[3849]: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: localhost
2020-11-24T13:21:55.357105+01:00 tuxedo accounts-daemon[3898]: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_get_object_path: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_INTERFACE_SKELETON (interface_)' failed
2020-11-24T13:21:55.460373+01:00 tuxedo kernel: [   41.604270] evdi: [I] Atomic driver:yes
2020-11-24T13:21:55.633656+01:00 tuxedo postfix/postmap[3909]: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: localhost
2020-11-24T13:21:56.334987+01:00 tuxedo lightdm[3891]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
2020-11-24T13:21:56.637588+01:00 tuxedo postfix/postmap[4045]: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: localhost
2020-11-24T13:21:57.647800+01:00 tuxedo postfix/postmap[4072]: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: localhost
2020-11-24T13:21:58.658359+01:00 tuxedo postfix/postmap[4115]: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: localhost
2020-11-24T13:21:59.682065+01:00 tuxedo postfix/postalias[4137]: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: localhost
2020-11-24T13:22:00.693740+01:00 tuxedo postfix[4156]: fatal: config variable inet_interfaces: host not found: localhost
2020-11-24T13:22:02.723068+01:00 tuxedo systemd[1]: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
2020-11-24T13:22:02.723915+01:00 tuxedo systemd[1]: postfix.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2020-11-24T13:22:02.930957+01:00 tuxedo lightdm: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
2020-11-24T13:22:03.447683+01:00 tuxedo lightdm[3891]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
2020-11-24T13:22:03.800107+01:00 tuxedo ksplashqml[4481]: QCoreApplication::arguments: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
2020-11-24T13:22:03.867724+01:00 tuxedo klauncher[4491]: Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
2020-11-24T13:22:04.105023+01:00 tuxedo ksmserver[4540]: Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
2020-11-24T13:22:04.179341+01:00 tuxedo udisksd[4558]: Can't load configuration file /etc/udisks2/udisks2.conf
2020-11-24T13:22:04.321407+01:00 tuxedo plasma_session[4518]: org.kde.plasma.session: failed to parse "/home/wo/.config/autostart/vboxinstall.sh.desktop" for autostart
2020-11-24T13:22:04.335680+01:00 tuxedo upowerd[4594]: energy_full (36.331800) is greater than energy_full_design (35.340000)
2020-11-24T13:22:04.352492+01:00 tuxedo kwin_x11[4545]: kf5.kconfig.core: "\"fsrestore1\" - conversion of \"0,0,0,0\" to QRect failed"
2020-11-24T13:22:04.369231+01:00 tuxedo kded5[4500]: org.kde.wacomtablet.common: d->name.isEmpty? true
2020-11-24T13:22:04.369406+01:00 tuxedo kded5[4500]: org.kde.wacomtablet.common: d->name.isEmpty? true
2020-11-24T13:22:04.630572+01:00 tuxedo kded5[4500]: kscreen.kded: UPower not available, lid detection won't work
2020-11-24T13:22:04.634646+01:00 tuxedo kded5[4500]: kscreen.kded: PowerDevil SuspendSession action not available!
2020-11-24T13:22:04.743637+01:00 tuxedo org_kde_powerdevil[4620]: powerdevil: No outputs have backlight property
2020-11-24T13:22:04.743839+01:00 tuxedo org_kde_powerdevil[4620]: powerdevil: Xrandr not supported, trying ddc, helper
2020-11-24T13:22:04.924390+01:00 tuxedo tracker-store[4689]: tracker_writeback_transact: assertion 'private == NULL' failed
2020-11-24T13:22:04.926352+01:00 tuxedo tracker-store[4689]: message repeated 2 times: [ tracker_writeback_transact: assertion 'private == NULL' failed]
2020-11-24T13:22:04.946814+01:00 tuxedo org_kde_powerdevil[4620]: powerdevil: Handle button events action could not check for screen configuration
2020-11-24T13:22:05.077122+01:00 tuxedo baloo_file[4548]: QDBusConnection: name 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2' had owner '' but we thought it was ':1.34'
```

Several of these lines contain strings such as "unable", "failed" or "fatal", but I have no idea if any of them point to something that might cause a sudden shutdown. Is it at all possible to find the cause of these power offs by inspecting log files or is this a hopeless undertaking?

Comment: The nvme error looks suspicious, you should check with smartctl if your disk is healthy.

Comment: @eblock Thanks for the hint. I have run smartctl several times since submitting this question but it reports "SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED" and "No Errors Logged".